# Why table shows no data using a custom table template in django-tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using django-tables to create a table from my model to display it on a page.

I have created the folowing `tables.py` file:

```
class OpenBetsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        fields = ("date", "time", "competition", "home",
                  "visitor", "bookie", "bet", "stake", "odds")
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm table-bordered"}
        empty_text = "Nothing to display"
```

I have a class-based view that contains the following:

```
queryset = user_bets.filter(status__name="New").order_by("-timestamp")
table = OpenBetsTable(queryset)
RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={'per_page': 10}).configure(table)
context["table"] = table
```

In the page's template I have added `{% load django_tables2 %}` and `{% render_table table %}` to render the table.

Everything works correctly until this point.

I want to use a custom template for the table so I added `template_name` in `OpenBetsTable`, using one of the templates provided with django-tables2:

```
class OpenBetsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        template_name = "django_tables2/table.html"
        fields = ("date", "time", "competition", "home",
                  "visitor", "bookie", "bet", "stake", "odds")
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm table-bordered"}
        empty_text = "Nothing to display"
```

Everything still works correctly.

As a sidenote, there are a few ways to use a custom table template as shown in [Is it possible to custom django-tables2 template for a specific page in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871550/is-it-possible-to-custom-django-tables2-template-for-a-specific-page-in-this-cas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Because I wanted to use my own custom table template, I created a html file called `bets_table.html`. I just copied the content from [django-tables2 default table template](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html).

The new table is below:

```
class OpenBetsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        template_name = "bets/bets_table.html"
        fields = ("date", "time", "competition", "home",
                  "visitor", "bookie", "bet", "stake", "odds")
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm table-bordered"}
        empty_text = "Nothing to display"
```

Using the table above, the table is rendered, the headers are displayed correctly but no data is shown, it displays the `empty_text` string from the table class. Another thing that is interesting is that the pagination controls display the number of available pages correctly.

I have looked in django debug toolbar and found out that in comparison the table with the custom table template has a few missing SQL queries. I am not sure why is that.

Comment: I'd suggest checking your `bets_table.html` code or posting it here. It looks like the problem is in the template code.

Comment: In the github template is `{% for row in table.paginated_rows %` which doesn't work. So I have replaced it with `{% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %}` that works. It seems the github template and the django-tables2 local template have this difference.