# How do I use AJAX for pagination in Django-Tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using django-tables2 and I am trying to display the data of the next page without loading another page. I think AJAX could be used.

From what I have found, it seems that it might not be possible.
There has been some discussion about this [Support AJAX sorting/pagination](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/17)

Is there something that I should look at to figure it out ?

Comment: Can definitely be done.  Make a view that produces a table, and have JavaScript handle clicks to the links on that table; then, get the refreshed view of the table and replace it (adding the handlers again, if need be).

Comment: From the link that you posted, it seems like they didn't add any ajax support (wow, that issue is over 7 years old). I know it's not the answer you are looking for but why not use a Bootstrap table instead? That way you can have more control over your layout. After that you can use standard Django pagination and use ajax requests easier. It also will look prettier.

Comment: You can also take a look at https://datatables.net/ if you're interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible however it's not so easy since django-tables2 (and django in general) are geared more to the Server Side Rendered world. I will sketch a solution here and consider that interesting topic for my blog (https://spapas.github.io):

- You'll need to override the django-tables2 template that'll be used. You can't use the default one since the pagination to it is done by normal links. You should override it to use Ajax calls - take a look at this question for more [Is it possible to custom django-tables2 template for a specific page in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871550/is-it-possible-to-custom-django-tables2-template-for-a-specific-page-in-this-cas). What you have to do is disable the default link functionality of the page links and call them through ajax. Depending on how you're going to do it this may be possible to be done through a `script` in your view's template without the need to override the table template at all.
- You'll need to modify your view to detect if it's called by ajax (i.e through these pagination buttons you've defined above) or not and return a different template each time. If it's called normally then you'll just render your classic template. If it is called through ajax then it will return only the portion of the html that only contains the table.
- Now in your normal template you'll put the table inside a `div` named (f.e) `#the_table` - when the user clicks on a pagination link you'll do the ajax call and the response will contain *only* the table - you'll then replace the contents of the `#the_table` `div` with what you just received.

So you should have two templates for your view, your `view.html` which will be something like:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content %}
blah blah

<div id='the_table'>
    {% include 'partial_table.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_script %}
    <script>
    // You can do something like (NOT TESTED):
    // I don't remember if the pagination links belong to a class 
    // if not you may want to add that class yourself
    $('pagination-link').click(function(e) {
        // Don't follow the link
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do the ajax request
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
            // Replace the table with what you received
            $('#the_table').html(data)
        });

    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And your `partial_table.html`:

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```

Now in your view if for example you are using CBVs then you'll have to use the `template_name = view.html` as defined above and override `get_template_names` like this:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    # Sometimes the is_ajax() is not working properly so if it doesn't 
    # just pass the ajax_partial query parameter to your ajax request
    if self.request.is_ajax() or self.request.GET.get('ajax_partial'):
        return 'partial_table.html'
    return super().get_template_names()
```

More info can be found in this recipe at my Django CBV guide: https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/#implement-a-partial-ajax-view

Comment: I have found an article that might be helpful: http://www.craigderington.me/solved-django-tables2-and-ajax/